# How can I not use $scope in an AngularJS Bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have this code inside a controller. I'm using it to open an angularJS Bootstrap modal with another controller attached.

Is there a way I can not use $scope for the ok() and cancel() functions here?

```
   $scope.deleteTest = (test: ITest) => {
        var self = this;
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/tests/partials/deleteTest.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'testService',
                function ($scope, $modalInstance, testService: ITestService) {
                    $scope.ok = () => {
                        var self = this;
                        testService.deleteTest()
                            .then(
                                () => {
                                    $modalInstance.close();
                                });
                    };
                    $scope.cancel = () => {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }],
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using TypeScript so you can do something like this

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/app/tests/partials/deleteTest.html',
    controller: DeleteTest,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
});

//...

class DeleteTest {
    static $inject = ['$modalInstance', 'testService'];

    constructor(private $modalInstance, private testService: ITestService) {

    }

    ok() {
        this.testService.deleteTest().then(() => this.$modalInstance.close());
    }

    cancel() {
        this.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

}
```

In `deleteTest.html` you could call the `ok()` method with something like

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.ok()">Ok</button>
```